# Case statement help for replacing null from multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

so i have the following case below  where if jl name does not have n/a i want it to come from the same column. if there is n/a i want to look into this subquery and find the recent jl name. but if the crecent.jl name is null i want to pull it from this other left join subquery that pulls the last record available  from temprosRecent.[JL name]. i found the record in the temprosRecent.[JL name] when i test it
separately but in my main query case statement below, i still get null for the record. is it due to the order of my case? i tried switching the order multiple times and didnt get it to work?

```
> ,CASE 
>           
>            WHEN EF.[JL name]!='N/A' then EF.[JL name]
>            
>            WHEN EF.[JL name]='N/A' THEN cRecent.[Jl_NAME]
>            
>            when cRecent.[Jl_NAME] IS null then temprosRecent.[JL name]
>           end as [NCW-Jl combo]
```

i am using sql 2012.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: BTW, that's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: If `cRecent.[Jl_NAME]` is not null and `EF.[JL name]` is null then tour case expression will return null as you dont have else clause

Comment: If you store NULL instead of N/A, life will become easier.

Comment: And if storing `NULL` in the source data is not an option, `NULLIF` is your friend (`NULLIF(EF.[JL name], 'N/A')`). That and a `COALESCE` should sort out most woes.

Comment: @Popeye thats what i am trying to figure out. what can i do if my cRecent.[Jl_NAME] is null when  EF.[JL name]='N/A' . if cRecent.[Jl_NAME] is null when  EF.[JL name]='N/A'  i want to use the temprosRecent.[JL name]

Comment: @jarlh  unfortunately data  comes as n/a for any non stored value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code handles the `'N/A'` cases and then defaults to returning `temprosRecent.[JL name]` when `EF.[JL name] is NULL`, the only remaining possibility. Note that it may still return null if `temprosRecent.[JL name]` is null.

Using `coalesce` handles the possibility of `cRecent.[Jl_NAME]` being null and returning `temprosRecent.[JL name]` instead.

```
CASE
  WHEN EF.[JL name] != 'N/A' then EF.[JL name]
  WHEN EF.[JL name] = 'N/A' THEN Coalesce( cRecent.[Jl_NAME], temprosRecent.[JL name] )
  ELSE temprosRecent.[JL name]
  end as [NCW-Jl combo]
```

Yes, the order is important. The result will be from the first matching condition. Note that short-circuiting is *not* guaranteed. If an expression has a side effect or might generate an error, e.g. divide-by-zero, that could occur even though the case is listed after the matching case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use extra condition in `when` clause and re-order it like this:

```
 ,CASE 
    WHEN EF.[JL name]!='N/A' then EF.[JL name]
    when cRecent.[Jl_NAME] IS null and EF.[JL name]='N/A' then temprosRecent.[JL name]
    WHEN EF.[JL name]='N/A' THEN cRecent.[Jl_NAME]
  end as [NCW-Jl combo]
```

Comment: tried this it did not work  still showing null